# Twisted Matrix Callback call again and again

Tags: python, loops, callback, twisted

I need that when a user click a button, that button fire the callback and pass her some parameters, each time, parameters will be different.

I've looked at documentation but appear that the part for looping is missing:

```
Looping

A common form of dependency is needing to perform the asynchronous operation all over again. The canonical example of this an HTTP redirect: when the callback for a deferred from a page request is returned, it could be the result, or it could be an empty body with the Location HTTP header set, in which case you simply perform the operation over again.

[ here is the HTTP redirect example. It also should have pictures. ]
```

the if is working, the try also, but the callback run just once

```
 if happen this:
  try:
     print "I'm here!"
     myobjectx.addCallback(test,x,y,z)  
     myobjectx.callback()

  except:
     ...
```

Just to get the idea of how this work:

```
1) create the myobject that do  nothing for now 
2) when an event is fired prepare the callback for the myobject e execute it 
3) how can I redo the callback next time the event happen again?
```

I'm looking at the pymodbus library example of async client:

https://pymodbus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous-client.html

I've got 2 files:

```
MAINPROCESS
MODBUSLIB
```

from MAINPROCESS I call

```
myobjectx = MODBUSLIB.protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, ModbusClientProtocol
        ).connectTCP("localhost", Defaults.Port)
```

then in a function triggered by an if:

```
if ('Gigiisclicked' in existkeys):

      myobjectx.addCallback(beginAsynchronousTest)
      myobjectx.callback(beginAsynchronousTest)
      print "executed"
```

and this is, the print is repeated again and again when the event occours but the callback no.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want a callback that runs each time a button is pressed?  Or do you want a single button press to result in a callback being called repeatedly?  If the latter, what determines how many times and when the callback is re-invoked?

Comment: I want a callback that runs each time a button is pressed, simply a one click to one execution relation. But now only first click work, next are ignored.

Comment: This question depends on the GUI library you're using, then.  It's difficult to answer without that information.

Comment: It's a web application, that talk with html pages using ajax. This part work, read the webclient request, perform some task and send back the data. But in the task I'm using pymodbus library that, perform the work with a callback(that work just once).

Comment: Please update your question with some of your (pymodbus-using) code.  Then I'll try to show you how to change it so it works multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one misunderstanding here is about how instances of `Deferred` are meant to be used.

You should think of `Deferred` as having two different kinds of (albeit highly related) uses.

One use is to be able to publish an event from some code that knows how to notice that events have happened to other code that might be interested to know that the event has happened.

One example of this use is `ClientCreator.connectTCP`: the implementation of this API knows when a TCP connection attempt has succeeded (or failed) and uses a `Deferred` to publish this information to other code.  Code that is using `Deferred` like this is code that actually instantiates `Deferred` (eg, `d = Deferred()`) and that later uses `Deferred.callback` and `Deferred.errback`.

The other use of `Deferred` is to allow code that is interested in events that has happened to learn that those events have happened.  For example, this your application that wants a TCP connection in order to exchange data - but needs to wait while one is being set up before it can proceed.  Code that is using `Deferred` like this is code that uses `Deferred.addCallback` or `Deferred.addErrback` (also, `Deferred.cancel` in recent versions of Twisted).

`Deferred.addCallback` is the API you use to specify what code to run when a `Deferred` eventually gets a result.

`Deferred.callback` is the API that you use to supply a result to a `Deferred`.  And, importantly, a `Deferred` can only ever be given one result.  Each `Deferred` instance represents the completion of a single operation or the occurrence of a single event.

There are certain some exceptions and some further subtleties but a good rule of thumb is that if your code didn't instantiate the `Deferred` then your code should not use its `callback` (or `errback`) methods.  Calling one of those is the job for whatever code created the `Deferred`.

Given that, I hope it's clear that the use of `Deferred` APIs in this code has some problems that need to be addressed:

```
myobjectx = MODBUSLIB.protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, ModbusClientProtocol
    ).connectTCP("localhost", Defaults.Port)

...

if ('Gigiisclicked' in existkeys):

    myobjectx.addCallback(beginAsynchronousTest)
    myobjectx.callback(beginAsynchronousTest)
    print "executed"
```

Most directly, you shouldn't be calling `myobjectx.callback` here.  That's `ClientCreator.connectTCP`'s job (on top of that, `beginAsynchronousTest` probably doesn't make sense as a result for this `Deferred` to have).

Instead, I think you want to use methods of the `ModbusClientProtocol` instance that `ClientCreator.connectTCP` will eventually create for you.  In the example you linked to, notice that `beginAsynchronousTest` is defined to accept one argument named `client`.

Since `beginAsynchronousTest` is passed to the `addCallback` method of the `Deferred` returned by `ClientCreator.connectTCP` this means it will be called with an instance of the protocol the `ClientCreator` was initialized with (in this case, `ModbusClientProtocol`).  `beginAsynchronousTest` will be called as soon as the `Deferred` is given its result by the implementation of `ClientCreator` - in other words, it will be called as soon as the connection is established.  Setting up a TCP connection takes a somewhat arbitrary amount of time since it involves exchanging data with arbitrary other computers over arbitrary network links - there's no telling how long those resources will take to complete their part of the connection setup.

Once `beginAsynchronousTest` is called you have a connection - represented by the `ModbusClientProtocol` instance passed in to it.  This is the point in your program where you might be able to start doing multiple things (for example, doing something each time a button is clicked).

At this point the `Deferred` your program started out with (called `myobjectx` in the snippets of code above) is done and no longer useful or interesting so you won't be using it anymore.

Instead, you'll be calling methods of `ModbusClientProtocol` (`read_coils` or `write_coil` or whatever else you want to do).  Each of these methods probably returns a brand new `Deferred` representing the result of that particular operation.  You'll want to use `addCallback` with these in order to learn about their results.

The other place people often stumble is figuring out how to make these additional method calls.  If you're adding code to the body of `beginAsynchronousTest` then it's fairly straightforward how to do this:

```
reading = client.read_coils(1, 1)
```

However, I suspect you won't want to add your button handling code to the body of `beginAsynchronousTest`.  Instead, you probably have an event handler somewhere else in your program that gets called any time a button has been pressed.  Fortunately, it's not much more complicated to deal with this situation.

The key is just to remember that any time you have a *reference* to the connection you'll be able to use it.  Inside the body of `beginAsynchronousTest` you have a reference to it - the `client` parameter.  You can make this reference available to other parts of your program too: setting an attribute on an object that is shared by the necessary parts of your program is one common, fairly good way to do this.

```
class ButtonModbusSomething(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None

    def connect(self):
        creator = MODBUSLIB.protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, ModbusClientProtocol)
        connecting = creator.connectTCP("localhost", Defaults.Port)
        connecting.addCallback(self._connected)
        connecting.addErrback(log.err)

    def _connected(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def buttonClicked(self, existkeys):
        if self.client is not None:
            if "Gigiisclicked" in existkeys:
                self.client.read_coil(1, 1)
```

Notice how the `client` attribute of `ButtonModbusSomething` starts off as `None` and how `buttonClicked` needs to check for this case.  As mentioned above, setting up a connection can take some time and the only way you know how long is to wait for `_connected` to be called.  This check ensures that if a button is clicked before the connection exists that the event is just ignored (you may want to handle this more nicely - for example, by starting with the user interface in a disabled state and then switching it on only when a connection is set up).

Also, I've left out the code that you probably also want to handle your connection being *lost*.  When this happens, the `client` attribute is no longer useful.  It is still a reference to the `ModbusClientProtocol` which was connected, but since that protocol instance no longer has a connection it's hard to do anything useful with.  You will probably want to re-disable the user interface when the connection is lost or at least start ignoring button presses again.

Also, notice that `ClientCreator` actually comes from `twisted.internet.protocol` not `MODBUSLIB.protocol`.